# Can you declare parameter-less methods in Java for use in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, setter, getter

In Scala we can have parameterless methods, which can be very useful for DSL purposes; they are also used for auto-defining getters for class fields.

I am developing a Java library that I would like to integrate as seamlessly with Scala as possible. I was wondering if there is a way to annotate a Java method with an empty parameter list so that Scala recognize it as parameterless.

For instance

```
class Foo {
  @ParameterLess
  public String[] bar() { return someArray; }
}
```

so that in Scala I can do:

```
val f = new Foo
f bar (0)
```

without having the compiler to complain about bar() having an empty argument list?

Alternatively, is there a way to define Scala-style getters and setter from Java?

Note: of course I know that in this particular example I can workaround the problem by defining

```
public String bar(int i) { return someArray[i]; }
```

Comment: Have you tried with bar(Object... os) ?

Comment: you need to call `f bar() (0)` in your example so that the compiler can differentiate between parameters and array index.

Comment: Of course. I was wondering if there was a way to hint to Scala  that `bar()` should act as `bar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably answers my question:

[Scala getters and setters in Java class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897307/scala-getters-and-setters-in-java-class)

The answer is that you can't, unless you resort to some trickery involving traits. Well, I guess that some kind of annotation à la `@scala.reflect.BeanProperty` would be a useful improvement.