# Scala setters and getters in a Java class

Tags: java, scala

I am trying to slowly convert a hybrid Scala/Java project piece by piece from Java to Scala. I have a class with a bunch of Scala setters and getters. Here is an example:

```
class inputParams {
  var _lakeHdfsPath: String = _
  var mandatoryParams = ArrayBuffer[String]()
  def lakeHdfsPath = this._lakeHdfsPath

  def lakeHdfsPath_=(_lakeHdfsPath: String) = {
    mandatoryParams -= "lakeHdfsPath"
    this._lakeHdfsPath = _lakeHdfsPath
  }
  ...
```

In my Java class I am trying to set this object, but running into difficulties:

```
retVal.lakeHdfsPath(cliOpts.getOptionValue("lakeHdfsPath"));
```

because in Scala it wants:

```
retVal.lakeHdfsPath = cliOpts.getOptionValue("lakeHdfsPath")
```

but in Java:

```
retVal.lakeHdfsPath() = (cliOpts.getOptionValue("lakeHdfsPath"));
```

And that doesn't work. How do I resolve this?

Comment: try `retVal.lakeHdfsPath_$eq(cliOpts.getOptionValue("lakeHdfsPath"));`

Comment: the name of scala setter is actually `lakeHdfsPath_=` but you cannot have `=` in java identifier, scalac changes this setter to be `lakeHdfsPath_$eq`. You can maybe see some more explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897307/scala-getters-and-setters-in-java-class . To get javalike getters, and setters you could use `@BeanProperty` annotation but I don't think it would work here as your setter does more than set. Optionally you could have both java and scala setters, i.e. in this case define additional `def setLakeHdfsPath(path: String) = { lakeHdfsPath = path }`

Answer (score 0):

In Scala you should stray away from mutable state whenever possible.  For beans you should implement them as case classes.  You get the setters and getters automatically.

```
case class inputParams (lakeHdfsPath: String) {
  def withLakeHdfsPath(newLakeHdfsPath: String): inputParams = 
    copy(lakeHdfsPath = newLakeHdfsPath)
}
```

Here you only need the `withLakeHdfsPath` method for java compatability, the copy method is accessible in Scala.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could change the setter in the Scala code and omit the equals in the def (=):

```
def lakePath_(_lakePath: String): Unit = {
        mandatoryParams -= "lakePath"
        this._lakePath = _lakePath
      }
```

And also define the return value for the getter:

```
   var _lakePath: String = _
      def lakePath(): String = this._lakePath
```

Then try the getter and setter on the java code:

```
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            //Instantiate the InputParams class.
            InputParams returnVal = new InputParams();

            //Setting _lakePath.
            returnVal.lakePath_("lakePath");

            //Getting _lakePath.
            String _lakePath = returnVal.lakePath();
            //Printing _lakePath to console.
            System.out.println(_lakePath);
        }
}
```